# Refactoring if statements using Ramda

Tags: javascript, typescript, ramda.js

I'm new to using Ramda so when I performed a map function (in my gatsby app) on an array of blog posts, within that map I used simple if statements. But I want to do this the right way, using Ramda all the way through, but I'm finding its many options overwhelming. I've definitely found and tried many examples from StackOverflow and elsewhere and have been able to grab the categories but not the whole blog post based on those categories. So while I realize there are examples out there I am struggling to apply them correctly in my instance. Any opinions about how I would refactor this code?

```
    const featured_post = [];
    const hrt_category = [];
    const work_category = [];
    const prep_category = [];
    const ed_category = [];

    {map(
        ({ node }) => {

            if (node.categories.some(e => e.slug === 'featured')) {
                featured_post.push(node);
            }
            if (node.categories.some(e => e.slug === 'hormones')) {
                hrt_category.push(node);
            }
            if (node.categories.some(e => e.slug === 'estrogen')) {
                work_category.push(node);
            }
            if (node.categories.some(e => e.slug === 'prep')) {
                prep_category.push(node);
            }
            if (node.categories.some(e => e.slug === 'ed')) {
                ed_category.push(node);
            }

        },posts
    )}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you replace `map` with a normal `Array.forEach` or simply a `for` loop - you'd get a simple to maintain, read and 0 dependencies code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To my mind, this is a misuse of Ramda (disclaimer: I'm a Ramda founder.)

Ramda is all about working with immutable data.  Although the internals of Ramda functions may mutate local variables, they never alter anything else.

Using `map` to create side-effects such as pushing to global variables is definitely a mismatch for Ramda.

Besides that, I am not a fan of this repetitive code.  My take would be radically different.  I wouldn't use all those global collections of posts.

Here's one possibility:

```js
const groupPosts = (names, posts) =>
  Object .fromEntries (names .map (name => [
    name, 
    posts .filter (
      ({node: {categories}}) => categories .some (({slug}) => slug == name)
    ) .map (({node}) => node)
  ]))

const posts = [{node: {id: 1, categories: [{slug: 'prep'}, {slug: 'ed'}]}}, {node: {id: 2, categories: [{slug: 'estrogen'}]}}, {node: {id: 3, categories: [{slug: 'ed'}]}}, {node: {id: 4, categories: [{slug: 'hormones'}, {slug: 'prep'}]}}, {node: {id: 5, categories: [{slug: 'featured'}]}}, {node: {id: 6, categories: [{slug: 'prep'}]}}, {node: {id: 7, categories: [{slug: 'estroogen'}]}},]

console .log (JSON .stringify (
  groupPosts (['featured', 'hormones', 'estrogen', 'prep', 'ed'], posts)
, null, 2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

But if you want those individual subcollections, we could extract from this the function that matches a single set of them:

```js
const matchSlugs = (name) => (posts) =>
  posts .filter (
    ({node: {categories}}) => categories .some (({slug}) => slug == name)
  ) .map (({node}) => node)
```

and we would use it like `const featured_posts = matchSlugs ('featured') (posts)` and our original function would be an easy gloss:

```js
const sortPosts = (names) => (posts) =>
  Object .fromEntries (names .map (name => [name, matchSlugs (name) (posts)]))
```

---

Note that this has not used Ramda anywhere.  We could start changing it to use Ramda's nicer `map` and `filter` functions, to use `toPairs` in place of `Object .fromEntries`, possibly to use Ramda's `any` in place of `.some`.  It might make this a bit cleaner, and I would recommend that you try if you're in the process of learning Ramda.  But that is the icing.  The cake is in simplifying the data structures and the code that use them.

## Update

The OP posted a Ramda-based refactoring of `matchSlugs` and asked for feedback.

Here is a series of refactorings of that version to a fully point-free version:

1. The OP's solution (with my own layout since comments don't allow us to display layout):

   ```js
   const matchSlugs = (name) => (posts) =>
     map (
       ({node}) => node, 
       filter(
         ({node: {categories}}) => any ((({slug}) => slug == name)) (categories),
         posts 
       )
     );
   ```
2. After pulling out the `posts` parameter:

   ```js
   const matchSlugs2 = (name) =>
     pipe (
       filter(({node: {categories}}) => any ((({slug}) => slug == name)) (categories)),
       map (prop ('node'))
     )
   ```

   This version separates the filtering of existing nodes from the final mapping of the results, and by putting those two steps into a `pipe` call, allows us to remove the second argument.  Note that `pipe` takes some functions and returns a function.  This retains the behavior above.
3. After cleaning up the destructured parameter in `filter`:

   ```js
   const matchSlugs3 = (name) =>
     pipe (
       filter (
         pipe (
           path (['node', 'categories']),
           any (({slug}) => slug == name)
         )
       ),
       map (prop ('node'))
     )
   ```

   Here we use `path (['node', 'categories'])` to replace the `({node: {categories}}` parameter.  That involves another `pipe` call, which I hope to clean up later.
4. After replacing the anonymous function with `propEq`

   ```js
   const matchSlugs4 = (name) =>
     pipe (
       filter (pipe (
         path (['node', 'categories']),
         any (propEq ('slug', name))
       )),
       map (prop ('node'))
     )
   ```

   This is just a minor fix, but `propEq` reads more cleanly to me than the lambda function.  It also will allow us to do the next refactoring.
5. After refactoring to remove the `name` parameter:

   ```js
   const matchSlugs5 = pipe (
     propEq ('slug'),
     any,
     flip (o) (path (['node', 'categories'])),
     filter,
     o (map (prop ('node')))
   )
   ```

   This is the largest step here.  We turn this into a point-free function, using two instances of `o`, Ramda's curried binary version of `compose`.  This is very useful in making functions point-free, but can feel fairly obscure.  (The name `o` is meant to remind us of the mathematical composition sign, `∘`.)  The first time we need to `flip` `o`, since Ramda does not have a `pipe`-style version of `o`.

For some Ramda users, this would be the ultimate goal, achieving a point-free version of the function.  There are times when that is quite readable, but I personally feel that this final step has *reduced* readability.  I might go back to an earlier pointed version, or, even better, to a version inspired by this one, but with the points reinstated:

```js
const matchSlugs6 = (name) => (posts) =>
  map (
    prop('node'), 
    filter (
      compose (any (propEq ('slug', name)), path (['node', 'categories'])),
      posts
    )
  )
```

To me this version is the most readable of the bunch.  But tastes differ, and you may find another one of these or an entirely different version most readable.

Comment: This is super helpful in terms of refactoring the code in general and I have implemented it in my local successfully. I'm tempted to leave as is but I think my colleagues are keen on using Ramda as much as possible so I may try to incorporate these last suggested changes as a next step. If you have any particular recs there happy to take them. Either way thanks a lot, this is much cleaner.

Comment: I would be wary of "using Ramda as much as possible".  Ramda is meant to be a utility library.  Use it where it helps, but don't try to squeeze everything into it.  By all means, spend some time learning what it can do, and I would hope that the more you use it, the more helpful it seems.  But there are plenty of places where it can offer nothing useful or where the quickly expanding vanilla JS has reduced the need for it.

Comment: In case anyone is curious here is how I refactored the matchslugs function to use ramda (I didn't actually need anything else for my current purpose). @Scott Sauyet feel free to critique how its done. Your knowledge has been super helpful.

```const matchSlugs = (name) => (posts) =>
  map(( { node }) => node, (filter( ({ node: { categories } }) =>
   any( (({ slug }) => slug == name))(categories), posts )
  ));```

[Sidenote: not sure why using markdown for code doesn't preserve the lines. Is it because this is a comment? I'll try to fix that to make it more readable]

Comment: Yes, comments don't get line-breaks.  It's a pain when you want to include snippets of formatted source code.  I understand why they don't do this in a Q&A site.  It's not supposed to be a discussion forum and comments are meant mostly to elicit clarifications.  But it's still a pain.

Comment: Updated with discussions of refactoring the Ramda version.

Comment: Wow. I just want to say thank you for this very thorough set of refactors. Super helpful to see the progression to make informed choices. I really appreciate the time you took to do this. TY!

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the nodes to an object of nodes by slugs, and then pick the requested slug in the stated order:

```js
const { mergeWith, concat, reduce, pick } = R

const mergeConcat = mergeWith(concat)

const groupPosts = (names, posts) => pick( // pick the names you want in the correct order
  names,
  reduce((p, { node }) => mergeConcat(p, // merge with the general categories
    reduce((c, { slug }) => // create an object of node by categories
      ({ ...c, [slug]: [node] }), {}, node.categories)
  ), {}, posts)
)

const posts = [{node: {id: 1, categories: [{slug: 'prep'}, {slug: 'ed'}]}}, {node: {id: 2, categories: [{slug: 'estrogen'}]}}, {node: {id: 3, categories: [{slug: 'ed'}]}}, {node: {id: 4, categories: [{slug: 'hormones'}, {slug: 'prep'}]}}, {node: {id: 5, categories: [{slug: 'featured'}]}}, {node: {id: 6, categories: [{slug: 'prep'}]}}, {node: {id: 7, categories: [{slug: 'estroogen'}]}},]

console.log (JSON.stringify (
  groupPosts (['featured', 'hormones', 'estrogen', 'prep', 'ed'], posts)
, null, 2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```